# MVC & Basic Data Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have experience with webForms and now i am starting to learn MVC, oh boy....everything looks so different. Since my background is webForms, I just want to make sure If am doing this properly. I am pulling data (Queries, Stored Procedures etc) from MS SQL Server & Goal is to represent them within view. here is what I have done so sar.

Here is my Model

```
Class Product ' Just a Template
  private _title 
  private _price
  ' property implementation etc
End Class

 Class ProductModel ' Returns Actual Data

    Function getProducts as list(of product)
      ' use SqlDataReader to Execute the Stored Procedure
      ' Populate a list(of product)
      ' list.add(new product(title,price))
      ' Return the List
     end function


   Function getTopProducts() as list(of products)

   End Function
End Class
```

Now Here is my **ProductsController** index() ActionMethod.

```
 Dim p as new ProductModel
 return view(p)
```

Then within my View (Which is strongly typed for **ProductModel** Class), I am using a For each on **Model.getProducts** or **Model.getTopProducts** and showing the data on screen.

Now Few questions...first of all, is my approach reasonable? is it a standard way of setting up Models with MVC? If not then please correct me.

Secondly, all the examples I see online, i see people using LINQ, EF etc....however in my environment performance is very important, and i am almost always returning data using Stored procedures, so is it OK to use pure ADO.NET or using LINQ/EF can help me out in some way?

Comment: using pure ado.net is consider to be the best solution incase if you don't know much about ORMs. Form performance reason (if you don't much tricks about ORM), ado.net is considered best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is my approach reasonable? is it a standard way of setting up
>   Models with MVC? If not then please correct me.

Yes, it's best practice to use a viewmodel than work with your entities directly on your views.

> is it OK to use pure ADO.NET or using LINQ/EF can help me out in some
>   way?

It's perfectly fine to use pure ADO.NET if you feel doing all the dirty works an ORM provides.

Comment: should I event bother passing instance of my Model Class(Product Model) to view from my controller? I can just make my view inherit from ProductModel Class and just use its entities within my view.

Comment: If you are "creating" a new model with a collection that goes with it then the answer is YES. You need to be able to pass the collections you need on your view from your controller. And you don't "inherit" a class on your view, you "use" (or consume) it.

Answer (score 1):

You approach is the one that is mostly shown when you learn about MVC. However, if you want to be a bit picky about naming convention then your `ProductModel` would be called `ProductViewModel`. This ViewModel will allow you to pass more information to View than it is available in your Product class (which is your model class). But this is insignificant although you should get used to using View with ViewModels.

As for your second question you can use anything you want as data access technology. Entity Framework is promoted by Microsoft as one of its technologies for manipulating with the information in a database. However, if you want you can use ADO.NET with stored procedures, or you can use RavenDB with its own client interface. It's really up to you.